# I'm trying to show the data in a order every data have to start from top

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to show the data in a order every data have to start from top. I have created a table and inside it I send a value. How can I show it like everything start from top? I have done some editing, but it doesn't come to top of the data shell. The arrangement is were bad. I need some help improve the style.

[image]

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">

</asp:Table>
   <table class="table" rules="all" 
    style="font-family: 'Arial Black'; font-size: small; text-transform: capitalize; table-layout: auto;" >

    <tr>

        <th>
           <strong>Channeling Paid and UnPaid Monthly</strong>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
                <asp:GridView ID="Ch_Data_Monthly" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" 
                AllowPaging="True">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </th>

        <th>
            <strong>Channeling Paid and UnPaid Daily</strong> 
             <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
            <asp:GridView ID="Ch_Data_Daily" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </th>
        <th>
            <strong> LabTest Income Amount Daily</strong>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
            <asp:GridView ID="LabTest_Profit_Daily" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>  
        </th>
        <th>
             <strong> LabTest Income Amount Monthly</strong>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
             <asp:GridView ID="LabTest_Profit_Monthly" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                 ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" 
                 HorizontalAlign="Center">
                 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </th>           

    </tr> 
    <tr>

        <th>
            <strong> OPD Income Amount Daily</strong>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
            <asp:GridView ID="OPD_Profit_Daily" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>  
        </th>
        <th>
             <strong> OPD Income Amount Monthly</strong>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
             <asp:GridView ID="OPD_Profit_Monthly" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                 ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" >
                 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </th>      
         <th>
            <strong> IPD  Income Daily</strong>         
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
            <asp:GridView ID="IPD_Profit_Daily" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                 ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </th>

        <th>
            <strong> IPD  Income Monthly</strong> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
            <asp:GridView ID="IPD_Profit_Monthly" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Height="25%" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>



        </th>


    </tr>
    <%--<tr>
        <th>

        </th>

    </tr>--%>

</table>
```

Comment: <th style="vertical-align: top">

Comment: it is working thanks a lot